# Order of zeros of $2(z-1)^n-e^{-z}$ in $B_1(1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I know there are $n$ zeros in the open ball $B_1(1)$ from Rouché's Theorem. However, how do I show that the order of these zeros are all one? I don't know where the zeros are, and this should be true for any arbitrary $n$. One thing I want to try is to show that $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ for any zero $z_0$, so we have
$$
f'(z) = 2n(z-1)^{n-1} + e^{-z}.
$$

Since $e^{-z_0} =2(z_0-1)^n$, this implies
$$
2n(z_0-1)^{n-1} + 2(z_0-1)^n = 2(z_0-1)^{n-1}(n+z_0-1).
$$

Now I am stuck on what to do, since I would have to show that neither of the two factors equals $0$. Any hints?

Comment: What can you say about $|z_0|$ if $z_0 - 1 = 0$ or $n+z_0-1= 0$?